# Chrome Extensions: chrome.storage.local not saving state

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-promise

I am trying to read a variable from `chrome.storage.local`, make some changes to it, save it back down, and read it back out again.

The problem arises after `searchAndHighlight(...)`. Inside that function, the local variable `nodesToClear` is set. This should in-turn be written to `chrome.storage.local`, to be re-used next time `searchAndHighlight(...)` runs.

*Note: I am using [chrome-promise](https://github.com/tfoxy/chrome-promise), to avoid old-school callbacks.*

**The Code**

```
import chromep from 'chrome-promise';

var nodesToClear = [];
chromep.storage.local.get('nodesToClear').then(function(data) {
    console.log('data.nodesToClear: ', data.nodesToClear); // Array of node objects
    console.log('ntc before: ', nodesToClear);
    if(Object.keys(data.nodesToClear[0]).length > 0) {
        console.log('typeof data.nodeToClear: ', typeof data.nodesToClear);
        nodesToClear = data.nodesToClear;
    }
    console.log('ntc after: ', nodesToClear);
}).then(function() {
    return chromep.storage.local.get(['ss', 'em', 'mc'])
}).then(function (data) {
    searchAndHighlight(data.ss, data.em, data.mc);
    chrome.storage.local.remove(['ss', 'em', 'mc']);
}).then(function() {
    console.log('ntc at end: ', nodesToClear);
    if(nodesToClear.length > 0) {
        chromep.storage.local.set({ nodesToClear: nodesToClear });
    }
}).then(function() {
    return chromep.storage.local.get('nodesToClear');
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log('ntc at end end: ', data.nodesToClear);
});
```

**The Output**

```
// data.nodesToClear:  [{…}]
// ntc before:  []
// ntc after:  []
// nodesToClear:  [span.myCssClass]
// ntc at end:  [span.myCssClass]
// ntc at end end:  [{…}]
```

**The Question**

- Notice how `ntc at end:  [span.myCssClass]` correctly states that local Array `nodesToClear` now contains one single Element node (an object).
- Notice also, after saving it down and reading it back out, it has been changed to an Array with an empty object inside: `ntc at end end:  [{…}]`. That is not the intention. It should read back out the same that was saved moments before.

Why is it not setting and getting the value properly?

---

### EDIT

Below follows a simplified piece of code, that demonstrates the same exact problem.

```
import chromep from 'chrome-promise';

var span = document.createElement('span');
span.classList.add('myClass');
var tn = document.createTextNode('blabla');
span.appendChild(tn);
var testVariable = span;

chromep.storage.local.set({testVariable: testVariable}).then(function() {
    console.log('testVariable: ', testVariable);
    return chromep.storage.local.get('testVariable');
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log('data.testVariable: ', data.testVariable);
});
```

Comment: I have only checked out the simplified code inside **Edit** and what is the problem here and probably in your full version is that you are storing DOM elements inside the storage, which doesn't work, you should instead store them as a string, for example.

Comment: You're not returning chromep.storage.local.set Promise so `.then()` doesn't wait for its completion and the next `chromep.storage.local.get` is invoked before the value is actually written in the storage.

Comment: @wOxxOm Is return not only needed if I want access to the data in the next `then`? I am guaranteed that one `then` will not run until the previous is finished. Thus, getting it after setting it is safe, as long as the `then`'s are chained. Is that not right?

Comment: No, the API doesn't guarantee it if you don't wait for resolution (or the callback in the vanilla chrome API).

Comment: @PredatorIWD According to bullet 5 in the intro in the docs (link below), objects can be stored. Link: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage. I need the reference to the object itself, so storing it as a string is not an option (I think?).

Comment: Wrong. Only JSONifiable portion of the object is stored e.g. `{}` for a DOM element.

Comment: Ok, thanks @wOxxOm . Two questions: 1) What do I do if i need to store a reference to an actual object, between runs of the content script? 2) What do I return in the first bulk, where there is not get / set?